# Редактор текста на странице сайта

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Всем доброго дня!Подскажите пожалуйста как подключить текстовый редактор на страницу сайта и возможно ли это вообще?В дизайне это выглядит вот так https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hbnarf725tknx1/img1.jpg?dl=0.Может есть какие-то специальные плагины ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.Хотел еще одно спросить, а можно как то данный редактор на русскоязычный вариант перестроить?

Comment: Кажется можно, поищите в документации.